# Date Times With Backbone, Rails 3.1, and MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, mongodb, backbone.js, mongomapper

I'm learning to use Backbone js with Rails and Mongo. Here are my models:

```
class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include ActionView::Helpers

  many :time_entries

  key :description, String
  key :duration, Integer, :default => 0
  timestamps!
end
```

and

```
class TimeEntry
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  belongs_to :task

  key :startDate, Date
  key :endDate, Date
end
```

For some reason, the date times that I send as startDate and endDate have the times dropped when updating mongo, but I can see backbone is pushing them through correctly:

```
Started PUT "/tasks/4f357ece8af1b04a54000ef2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-11 12:25:19 -0500
Processing by TasksController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"description"=>"Task with time entry", "time_entries"=>[{"startDate"=>"2012-02-11T17:25:19.529Z"}], "created_at"=>"2012-02-10T20:32:14Z", "duration"=>0, "id"=>"4f357ece8af1b04a54000ef2", "updated_at"=>"2012-02-11T17:25:00Z", "task"=>{"description"=>"Task with time entry", "time_entries"=>[{"startDate"=>"2012-02-11T17:25:19.529Z"}], "created_at"=>"2012-02-10T20:32:14Z", "duration"=>0, "id"=>"4f357ece8af1b04a54000ef2", "updated_at"=>"2012-02-11T17:25:00Z", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"tasks"}}
MONGODB    timetrack_development['tasks'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f357ece8af1b04a54000ef2')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB timetrack_development['tasks'].update({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f357ece8af1b04a54000ef2')}, {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f357ece8af1b04a54000ef2'), "description"=>"Task with time entry", "duration"=>0, "created_at"=>2012-02-10 20:32:14 UTC, "updated_at"=>2012-02-11 17:25:19 UTC, "time_entries"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f36a47f8af1b04a54000ff9'), "task_id"=>nil, "startDate"=>2012-02-11 00:00:00 UTC}]})
```

Notice that rails is getting my startDate and endDate params correctly as ISO8601 formatted strings in the params, but the call to update sets the time piece to 00:00:00. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're losing the time-of-day because you're using `Date` where you mean `Time`. The MongoMapper [types documentation](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/types.html) pretty much says "read the source" so we'll do that; if you look at [`extensions/time.rb`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/extensions/time.rb) you'll see that it works with Time instances but if you look at [`extensions/date.rb`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/extensions/date.rb) you'll see that it works with Date instances:

```
def to_mongo(value)
  #...    
  date = value.is_a?(::Date) || value.is_a?(::Time) ? value : ::Date.parse(value.to_s)
  ::Time.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day)
  #...
end

def from_mongo(value)
  value.to_date if value.present?
end
```

So any time-of-day on `startDate` or `endDate` goes away on the way in and out of MongoDB.

Try defining your TimeEntry like this:

```
class TimeEntry
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  belongs_to :task

  key :startDate, Time
  key :endDate, Time
end
```